# running systemctl with sudo throws "Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory"

Tags: centos

I am trying to disable firewall on CentOS7.3 on Azure with the following:

```
sudo systemctl disable iptables-services firewalld
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
"Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory"
```

What is interesting is that when I run this without sudo, OS seems to be finding the files and I get the following:

```
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: root
```

But then I fail at authentication (since root account is disabled, I login with SSH key).

Any suggestions how to move forward are appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be using the wrong service name for the iptables service.

Also, if you have a default centos install, I would assume firewalld is in place (rather than the iptables _service) - so if you really want to stop all firewalling, probably `systemctl stop firewalld` will do for now (and `systemctl disable firewalld` if you *really* mean to do that).

Easiest is probably to confirm that part is correct:

`sudo systemctl | grep iptable`

The error message is down to the fact there is no unit file found called iptables-services.service, in any of systemd's search paths.

To quickly illustrate:

`sudo systemctl status nosuchthing
Unit nosuchthing.service could not be found.`

vs something that does exist:

`sudo systemctl status sshd
sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)`

The path shown is not the only one that systemd looks at, in passing.

Unless you are doing this to install a different firewall manager/front-end, I would however tend to want to suggest leaving firewalld in place, and open the ports you need.

Firewalld is fairly straightforward (see docs: http://www.firewalld.org/), and opening up a specific port is a simple matter of (again, assuming default centos7): `sudo firewall-cmd --zone public --add-port=PORT/PROTO --permanent && sudo firewall-cmd reload`

Comment: Awesome, thank you, iptables-services is not place! :)